# Homeomorphism of the cone on a space

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

The unreduced cone $\text{Cone}(X)$ on a space $X$ is given by $$ \text{Cone}(X)=X\times I/ X\times \{1\}$$ where $I$ is a unit interval.
Show that Cone($S^{n-1}$) is homeomorphic to $D^{n}$ where $S^{n-1}=\left\{x\in R^{n}| \left\| x \right\|=1 \right\}$ and $D^{n}=\left\{x\in R^{n}| \left\| x \right\| \leq 1 \right\}$.

Intuitively I want to construct a homeomorphism by projecting some part of the cone into the interior of the sphere. But I don't know how to carry it out by using accurate mathematical language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ denote the apex of the cone $\text{Cone}(S^{n-1})$. For each $x\in S^{n-1}$ and each $t\in[0,1]$ let $c(x,t)\in \text{Cone}(S^{n-1})$ satisfying

$$ c(x,t)=(1-t)p+tx$$

Then let $f: \text{Cone}(S^{n-1})\to D^n$ be defined by

$$ f(c(x,t))=tx $$

This continuously maps $\text{Cone}(S^{n-1})$ onto $D^n$ and its inverse continuously maps $D^n$ onto $\text{Cone}(S^{n-1})$.

Comment: Thank you.I have another question which requires me to prove that $CS^{n-1}$ is homeomorphic to $D^{n}$ where $CX$ is the reduced cone s.t. $CX=X\times I / x_{0}\times I\cup X\times 1$ .If I apply your method in this case,it's not gonna work since we'll miss a slice. How can we deal with this case?